# How to use an ASP.NET Core environment variable in testing with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, environment-variables, integration-testing, visual-studio-2017

In my integration tests, I want to set a specific connection string when the test runs in a development environment, and another connection string when the test runs in the staging environment.

When I am not in testing mode, I simply set the environment variable on the machine, and all work OK. But on testing I can use `UseEnvironment(envX)`, but then it'll be `envX` on all machines, or not use this method, and get the default one (which is production).

So, how can I use multiple connection strings, environment based, in my integration tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `UseEnvironment(envX)` you could set the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` before running the tests.

I.e. `SET ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Test` and `SET ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=SomeOtherEnvironment`

Comment: where I set the environment variable when I'm running unit test in Visual studio?
I run this command on cmd, but then when debugging test I can see that env.name is still production

Comment: I don't think you can currently do this if you are just running it in Visual Studio. If you are running from the console or write a small script, you can first set the environment variable and then run `dotnet test`.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `IHostingEnvironment` to check the environment in integration test code, then you may override value in `IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName`:

```
//IHostingEnvironment env;

env.EnvironmentName = 'Development';
env.IsDevelopment() // return true;

env.EnvironmentName = 'TEST';
env.IsDevelopment() // return false;
env.IsEnvironment('TEST') // return true;
```

Comment: how this help me when running the same test on multiple envs? the same test should run sometimes on envX and sometimes on envY

Answer (score 0):

If you are running `dotnet test`, you can set the environment variable in your PowerShell window locally first:

```
 $env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="test"
 dotnet test
```